# MongoDB - Increment a field using another array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a collection with the document of this structure:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63e8af476a3674484ea14888"
  },
  "my_id": 321123,
  "version": 0,
  "parameters": [
    {"a": 1},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2}
  ]
}
```

Using a RESTful API the user can change the `version` field to any number between 0 and `len(parameters)`. Another endpoint let the user push an object to `parameters` and set `version` to the new `len(parameters) - 1`. So using the previous example, after using this endpoint we will get:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63e8af476a3674484ea14888"
  },
  "my_id": 321123,
  "version": 2,
  "parameters": [
    {"a": 1},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
  ]
}
```

I tried many things, but nothing seems to work. Here are examples of what I tried:

```
db.parameters.findOneAndUpdate({"my_id": 321123}, {"$inc":{version: parameters}, "$push":{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}, upsert=true)
db.parameters.findOneAndUpdate({"my_id": 321123}, {"$inc":{version: {"$size": parameters}}, "$push":{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}, upsert=true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your update requires referring to another field, you have to use the [update query with the aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

For the first scenario,

1. Add a new parameter object by combining it with the current `parameters` array via `$concatArrays`.
2. I don't think that increment is what you need, but rather update the `version` value via `$set` stage. An example as below is to compare the `version` param between the range of 0 and `len(parameters)`, if true, then update with the `version` param, else update with the size of the `parameters` array.

```
db.parameters.update({
  "my_id": 321123
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      parameters: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$parameters",
          [
            {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2,
              "c": 3
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      version: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  2,
                  // version
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  2,
                  // version
                  {
                    $size: "$parameters"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: 2,
          else: {
            $size: "$parameters"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Demo (1st scenario) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WFfQB6f6zKU)

---

For the second scenario,

1. Add a new parameter object by combining it with the current `parameters` array via `$concatArrays`.
2. Set the `version` with the size of `parameters` array minus 1.

```
db.parameters.update({
  "my_id": 321123
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      parameters: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$parameters",
          [
            {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2,
              "c": 3
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      version: {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            $size: "$parameters"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Demo (2nd scenario) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8qKCD0bLL4b)

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I don't need the subtract function because size([{},{}]) is 1. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: I don't think an array with 2 objects will give you size/length as 1.